# Replaceregexp with property value depending on the matched group

Tags: ant, replace

I'd like to replace some replace marks in css files with values out of a property file. What i did so far is:

```
<target depends="prepare" name="build_css">
    <replaceregexp>
        <fileset refid="temp_css_files"/>
        <regexp pattern="\{(.*)\}"/>
        <substitution expression="${testprop}"/>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

which will successfully replace the matched string with the value of the testprop property.But what i like to do is, to replace the matched string by a property whose name is the matched string.

So a replacement mark `{myprop}` will be replaced by the value of the property `myprop`.

I tried:

```
<target depends="prepare" name="build_css">
    <replaceregexp>
        <fileset refid="temp_css_files"/>
        <regexp pattern="\{(.*)\}"/>
        <substitution expression="${\1}"/>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

with no success since the matched string is then replaced by the String `${myprop}`.

Is it possible to to this? Or is there an easier way with another task that i'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the typical Ant `${...}` syntax to represent properties in your CSS files, then Ant's [`<expandproperties>` FilterReader](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#expandproperties) may be useful:

```
<project name="ant-replace-tokens-with-copy-task" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <property name="src-root" location="src"/>

        <fileset id="temp_css_files" dir="${src-root}">
            <include name="**/*.css"/>
        </fileset>

        <!-- The <copy> task cannot "self-copy" files. So, for each -->
        <!-- matched file we'll have <copy> read the file, replace the -->
        <!-- tokens, and write the result to a temporary file. Then, we'll -->
        <!-- use the <move> task to replace the original files with the -->
        <!-- modified files. -->
        <property name="filtered-file.extension" value="*.filtered-file"/>

        <copy todir="${src-root}">
            <fileset refid="temp_css_files"/>
            <globmapper from="*" to="${filtered-file.extension}"/>
            <filterchain>
                <expandproperties/>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>

        <move todir="${src-root}">
            <fileset dir="${src-root}" includes="**"/>
            <globmapper from="${filtered-file.extension}" to="*"/>
        </move>
    </target>
</project>
```

If you need to stick with the `{...}` syntax, the [ReplaceTokens FilterReader](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replacetokens) replaces tokens with properties defined in a properties file:

```
<project name="ant-replace-tokens-with-copy-task" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <property name="src-root" location="src"/>

        <fileset id="temp_css_files" dir="${src-root}">
            <include name="**/*.css"/>
        </fileset>

        <!-- The <copy> task cannot "self-copy" files. So, for each -->
        <!-- matched file we'll have <copy> read the file, replace the -->
        <!-- tokens, and write the result to a temporary file. Then, we'll -->
        <!-- use the <move> task to replace the original files with the -->
        <!-- modified files. -->
        <property name="filtered-file.extension" value="*.filtered-file"/>

        <copy todir="${src-root}">
            <fileset refid="temp_css_files"/>
            <globmapper from="*" to="${filtered-file.extension}"/>
            <filterchain>
                <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens">
                    <param type="tokenchar" name="begintoken" value="{"/>
                    <param type="tokenchar" name="endtoken" value="}"/>
                    <param type="propertiesfile" value="dev.properties"/>
                </filterreader>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>

        <move todir="${src-root}">
            <fileset dir="${src-root}" includes="**"/>
            <globmapper from="${filtered-file.extension}" to="*"/>
        </move>
    </target>
</project>
```